# Java.Net.ConnectException: connection refused

Tags: java, connection

I am doing my final year project on Java platform under Ubuntu and at first I was getting a permission denied error i.e, `java.net.bindexception:permission denied` but after increasing the port number I've resolved that.

Now on the client side I am getting a `connection refused` error. I  have pinged both server and client and both are working fine; I am using java sdk 7 for this project.

I cant resolve this `connection refused` error but the same code is working fine under Windows, any suggestions?

Comment: You may get a better response from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) than you are likely to here as it's much more orientated towards programming than this site.  Your first error is because port numbers below 1024 are reserved and you need root privileges to open them.  We would need to see your code to advise further but I suggest you ask on a programming site such as [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [Development and Programming](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=310) on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forum.php)

Answer (score 0):

To use port numbers below 1000, you need root privileges. To bind on a number lower than 1000, run it with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

For use the port range 0-1023 you need root privileges.

Comment: I have run using sudo only but then also it is not working

Comment: You can try to telnet the server app, it looks like there is nothing listening on destionation port. Try `telnet server-ip applicationport`